# How to install Glade 3.22 on Windows 10?

Tags: user-interface, windows-10, gtk, glade

I'm trying to figure out how to install Glade on Windows, but I can't find anything helpful (I have never dealt with manual installs before so if that's required, please point me to a walkthrough).

The Glade homepage (https://glade.gnome.org/index.html) seems dead, broken links everywhere and the sources and binaries links only contains old versions of Glade.

I finally found where to download the latest on the wiki: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Glade

But that gives me a .flatpakref file that I have no idea what to do with on my Windows machine.

I also found the up-to-date source files (https://download.gnome.org/sources/glade/), but again I'm not familiar with manual installations so I don't know what to do with that, and the "INSTALL" help file in there makes little to no sense...

Is there no longer any support for Glade on Windows, do I just need to install a virtual machine for Linux and and install it there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Building gtk/gtkmm manually on Windows is an absolute pain. Since Microsoft has included both gtk and gtkmm as vcpkg ports, I hope that they would also include glade in the near future. I have requested a new port for glade. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981763/how-to-install-glade-3-22-on-windows-10#comment103273569_58012362).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GTK development on Windows is mostly done through vcpkg or MSYS2 packages, as stated in the [GTK installation instructions for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/). Once you have a package manager, you can just use the package manager to install the latest glade version. I never did it with vcpkg, but the instructions to install Glade from MSYS2 are on that page (just search "glade" there).

If you chose the MSYS2 way, you will then easily install Glade with:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glade
```

Comment: I didn't realize it went into installing Glade, I just thought it was installing GTK only, which I don't need to do since I'm using Julia for my backend.  Also, I wasn't familiar with MSYS2.  This worked flawlessly, thanks!  Only issue is that the **pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-devhelp** command gives a "target not found" error...

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the instructions for the MSYS2 part, and know that people generally need other tools like glade or devhelp, so I just decided to include their installation in the procedure, as installing GTK+ is the main entry point for newcommers. Once you have a package manager, you can have pretty much everything you want. However, yes, it seems that devhelp isn't packaged anymore by MSYS2. Might be a packaging problem due to the dependency on webkit, which would have them remove the package.

Comment: I've opened [issue 5805](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5805) on MSYS2 to track that.

Comment: I have requested a new vcpkg glade port. Please track [issue#8182](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/8182) for up to date info.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a Windows Build with all needed dependencies...

https://github.com/subabrain/gladeui-3.4.0-windows

or just use msys2 and download the gladeui package and then just go to the bin folder and start gladeui.exe

Answer (score 0):

here you can find an updated (3.40.0) version of Glade build for Win64 with all deps:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glade/uploads/86727531bbfe8b0bc60b8d6a01765e75/glade3.40_Win64_UCRT64_20230912.7z